# Know when somebody comments on my post

Tags: c#, facebook, events, comments

I have an application and I am feeding posts to my wall. There are times when people are putting comments on my posts. Is there any way I know that I have a comment on my post, the post ID and any other information so I can send a Like to their comment? And also I need to know if someone likes my post so I can thank him back for his "Like".
I am using the SDK version 5 and I am writing C#.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get realtime updates for Page post updates, but you could poll the Post object you made (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/ ) via its ID, and pull the list of comments and likes from there

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has a [real-time updates API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/) that you can use on user/page information and should eventually be able to use for posts.  However in the documentation it says:

> "You can't subscribe to these user connections yet: home, tagged,
>   **posts**, photos, albums, videos, groups, notes, events, inbox, outbox,
>   updates, accounts. *We will add support for more properties and
>   connections in the future.*"

For now, you will need to poll the Graph API every so often to check.

When your app publishes a post, the API returns an ID.  You can later use that ID to get the comments and like by going to /objectID/comments and /objectID/likes.  To post a comment, do an HTTP Post to /objectID/comments, and to like a comment/post, issue an HTTP post to /objectID/likes.

This is all documented on the [Facebook API documentation.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

Comment: Is it possible to tell me how? I 've been trying for long time and I couldn't find the way